# How to select the second text node via JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I want to **SELECT** the text nodes that is not under an element. But I want to **SELECT** them 1 by 1.

Like for example I only want to **SELECT** the second text node which is "Baths:".

Will that be possible?

I am doing this so I can add some icons before those text Nodes.

**Here are the codes:**

```
<div class="property-info">
Beds: <strong>3</strong> 
<br> 
Baths: <strong>2</strong> 
<br> 
Sq. Ft.: <strong> 1,055 </strong> 
<br> 
Type: <strong>Condo</strong> 
<br>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To do what? ... Also do you control the html structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? You want the Bath value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Comment: Probably check https://stackoverflow.com/a/4399718/1268350

Comment: @charlietfl: No, I dont have the control on the html structure, it was dynamically created by a plugin.

mathias: I need to select the text nodes. Each one of them.

Comment: @MarkLozano What you are going to do with them ?

Comment: @SureshAtta I need to select them so I can add some icons before those text nodes.

Comment: @MarkLozano https://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/nkv3qv0w/1/ ???

Answer (score 2):

One approach that iterates `contents()` and checks if a text node's next sibling is `<strong>` and uses object to store icon html based on text

```js
var icons = {
  "Beds:": '[bed-icon]',
  "Baths:": '[bath-icon]'
}


$('.property-info').contents().each(function() {
  var $node = $(this);
  if (this.nodeType === 3 && $node.next().is('strong')) {
    var icon = icons[$node.text().trim()] || '';
    $node.before(icon);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="property-info">
  Beds: <strong>3</strong>
  <br> Baths: <strong>2</strong>
  <br> Sq. Ft.: <strong> 1,055 </strong>
  <br> Type: <strong>Condo</strong>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the HTML with regular expressions:

```js
var html = $('.property-info').html();
$('.property-info').html(html.replace(/(\s*)([^:\W]*)(.*)<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/g, '<i class="icon $2-icon">i</i> $2$3<strong>$4</strong>'));
```

```css
.icon {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  min-width: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.Beds-icon {
  background-color: green;
}

.Baths-icon {
  background-color: red;
}

.Sq-icon {
  background-color: blue;
}

.Type-icon {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="property-info">
  Beds: <strong>3</strong>
  <br>
  Baths: <strong>2</strong>
  <br>
  Sq. Ft.: <strong> 1,055 </strong>
  <br>
  Type: <strong>Condo</strong>
  <br>
</div>
```

The regular expression used: `/(\s*)([^:\W]*)(.*)<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/g`

Replaced with the string: `<i class="icon $2-icon">i</i> $2$3<strong>$4</strong>`

Then some CSS applied to make it look like icons.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the answer, But I dont want to extract them.
I just want to select them so I will be able to add some icons before those text nodes.

Comment: @MarkLozano Try running my example now. I think it's close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/seo8mpoy/

*HTML Added spans so you can grab the text. NOTE!! i added spans you need to add them aswel.

```
 <div class="property-info">
 <span>Beds:</span><strong>3</strong> 
 <br> 
 <span>Baths:</span> <strong>2</strong> 
 <br> 
 <span>Sq. Ft.:</span> <strong> 1,055 </strong> 
 <br> 
 <span>Type:</span> <strong>Condo</strong> 
 <br>
 </div>
```

jquery

```
$('.property-info').on('click',function(){
  var t = $(this).find('span');
  t.each(function( index ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
  });
});
```

Comment: Its not magic. it is added by me so you can pick out the text, Cant fix code without adding stuff or removing stuff :P lol

Comment: No mention of that in the answer and is not same markup as in question

Comment: Last time i try to help on stack overflow!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but the code I pasted was dynamically created by a plugin. That is why I need to select the text nodes.

Comment: Take it easy @NicholasO'Malley, the life is so short...@charlietfl just wanted to help you improve your answer.

Comment: Stil not helping on stack anymore. To much work if people need me to explain i added a god dam span, and the way people "help" is like playing a bad game of LOL

Comment: Actually this answer gave me an idea on adding a span via jquery, Check my answer, the last one.

PS. I dont like LOL. I prefer Dota 2. XD

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $('.property-info')[0].childNodes[0].data;
```

gives you text for node 0

and if you want to add something before or after this

```
$('.property-info')[0].childNodes[0].data = text + 'something';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code for extracting only text and add whatever you want to add before it.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91n23Lz/205/)

HTML Code-

```
<div class="property-info">
  Beds: <strong>3</strong>
  <br> Baths: <strong>2</strong>
  <br> Sq. Ft.: <strong> 1,055 </strong>
  <br> Type: <strong>Condo</strong>
  <br>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT Code-

```
var data = $(".property-info").contents();
console.log(data);
count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].nodeName == "#text" && data[i].nodeValue.trim().length > 0) {
    data[i].nodeValue = "icon code goes here" + data[i].nodeValue;
    console.log(data[i].nodeValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shubham I find this interesting and it does insert the icons before it.
But the case is i will use different icons for each one of them.
That is why I need to select each one of them.

Comment: @MarkLozano you can insert different icons with each text by putting conditions over text value.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all your answers and still did some research.

Here's what I came up to:

**This Code "wraps" all the nodes with a "span", I added a class "text_nodes" on it.**

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery('.property-info')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
  }).wrap('<span class="text_nodes"/>');
});
```

**And Because the text nodes are now wrap up, I can easily select them individually via css and add the icons as "content".**

```
 <div class="property-info">
 <span class="text_nodes">Beds:</span><strong>3</strong> 
 <br> 
 <span class="text_nodes">Baths:</span> <strong>2</strong> 
 <br> 
 <span class="text_nodes">Sq. Ft.:</span> <strong> 1,055 </strong> 
 <br> 
 <span class="text_nodes">Type:</span> <strong>Condo</strong> 
 <br>
 </div>
```

**Here's the css code that I used to add icons. (PS I used unicodes for icons)**

```
.property-info > span:nth-child(1):before {
    content: '\f236';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.property-info > span:nth-child(2):before {
    content: '\f2cd';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.property-info > span:nth-child(3):before {
    content: '\f015';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Here's how it looks now.

[image]

Thank you very much for those who helped and answered. You all gave Me an idea on how to solve this problem. :)